# Перенос строки

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api, text

Вывел текст со стены группы ВК (с помощью wall.get), но текст не переносится на новые строки, как в ВК. `echo str_replace('\r\n', '<br/>', $text);` - не помогает. В чем проблема?

Comment: А какой разделитель используется в тексте?

Comment: @maxleo, неизвестно. В примере API текст правильно отображается, а на деле в строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

90% что вместо `'\r\n'` нужно просто `"\n"` (внимание на двойные кавычки).